# Vagrant. The box you're attempting to add doesn't support the provider you requested

Tags: vagrant

I created a vagrant box using `vagrant package` , uploaded it and released it.
Then I did `vagrant init <username>/<box>` which created a Vagrantfile. I even appended the box version to the Vagrantfile.
Next I did `vagrant up --provider virtualbox`. This tries to get the box locally and then when it can't find it, i get the error:

```
The box you're attempting to add doesn't support the provider
you requested. Please find an alternate box or use an alternate
provider. Double-check your requested provider to verify you didn't
simply misspell it.

If you're adding a box from HashiCorp's Atlas, make sure the box is
released.
```

I have given virtualbox as the provider and virtual box works fine with other boxes I use.

Comment: can you run `vagrant box list` to check which box you have available. The fact you have packaged an existing VM as a box does not mean you have it installed

Comment: I repeated the process again and it worked this time. Still figuring out where i had gone wrong earlier. Thanks though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I figured was that due to some reason vagrant had got corrupted. So doing a fresh install of vagrant did the trick.

Comment: Mine just needed upgrading to a new version.

Comment: For me, @SLIMANI's answer was correct. Needed to add `virtualbox-qt` on my Ubuntu 20.04 system.

Answer (score 8):

Make sure you have virtualbox installed if you are using ubuntu.

```
sudo apt install virtualbox-qt
```

Answer (score -1):

1 - access the terminal (sudo) and, remove vagrant files

```
$ rm -rf /opt/vagrant

$ rm -f /usr/bin/vagrant
```

2 - then install it again as it has probably been corrupted.

```
$ curl -O https://releases.hashicorp.com/vagrant/2.2.9/vagrant_2.2.9_x86_64.deb
```

3 - install vagrant

```
$ sudo apt install ./vagrant_2.2.9_x86_64.deb
```

4 - confirm by viewing the installed vagrant version

```
& vagrant --version
```

Comment: None of these appear to work with Windows 11 and Virtualbox 7.0.12

Corruption is not the issue, as I did the full reinstall.